# Weird text shows on a billboard TV

Tags: xubuntu, tty

I've got a 14m2 digital billboard with a computer behind which is working on Xubuntu.

Everything works just fine when it's turned on, the ads are showing correctly and stuff like that, but I need to change those ads. When I used to turn the computer and the digital billboard on it starts and after the boot screen that says Xubuntu it goes straight to the ads (so the ads start playing automatically when the PC turns on).

After reading some things about Ubuntu I wanted to go and use the interface of the computer like in Windows, so I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1-F7 and there goes my problem. The only thing that my monitor displays is some weird text which looks like the text isn't being decoded.

[image: jumbled text on a monitor]

Managed to get in the computer by remote after connectin 2 computer with crossover cable. All i can do now is manage the ads by the tecnovision dlx player and server. I still cant open that computer like a normal computer working on linux.

Comment: I'm new here and i can't post pictures so i can explain better. Whatever i press from Ctrl - Alt - F1 to F6 nothing is readable on the screen. My problem is that i can't login because i can't read the text.

Comment: Is this small (TTY) text on the billboard, and does the billboard have the resolution to render them properly? Try switching the output to a normal monitor, if the text looks OK there it's an issue with the billboard. Also, why are you trying to switch to TTY? It seems like it would be easier to use the GUI. Just curious, there's probably a good reason.

Comment: It would be great to know how do i use the GUI. As i said when i turn it on, it directly starts the ads and i can do nothing. If i press anything on the keyboard it just navigates through ads. Ive been using it with a monitor also and still the same thing. 

Comment: What is the application that automatically runs full-screen ads at boot? And what does its documentation say about how to exit the application and return to the desktop GUI?

Comment: I don't know the name of any app. When i turn it on, in the monitor i can see the spec of the computer afer that the xubuntu logo and then ads. That's all.

Comment: OK, there's not much to work with here but try logging in over TTY, run `ps` to see which processes your user is running (or `ps aux` for all processes system-wide) and add that list of running processes to your question please.

Comment: Can i send you a picture somehow so you can tell me how to login over TTY while i can't read what's written on the screen.

Comment: Try any image sharing service and use the interpunct "·" as a workaround if you cannot post images or links to images. If you press CTRL+ALT+F3 and type your username, press enter, type your password, and press enter again, you will be logged in. You can do this without even looking at the screen.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/DHbhTAJZqrDrpx68A i hope u can see that

Comment: OK, I edited that into the body of your question. I'm afraid I have no idea how to troubleshoot further but perhaps someone else will see the image and know what has gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks alot man. I appresciate your help. 

Comment: Looks to me like it's not switching from the display mode that's been used for the ads to one that can render the text. I would try booting straight to command line, so in grub choose your recovery option. If you don't have that then is there any reason you can't attach the computer to a regular monitor and try that?

Comment: @pbhj thanks for responding. I've been using that with a regular monitor (actually any type of monitor) but i still get the same feedback. Im stuck in here and i can't do nothing. I really need some help on this one.

Comment: Well if you can't access grub, then you should be able to boot from a CD or USB to a live distro (eg Xubuntu installer USB) and then look at the X11 settings. Is this over HDMI? It sounds like you don't know much about the system, have you checked whether it has VNC or SSH open for you to login from a remote computer to administer it?

Comment: Yes @pbhj thats true. I don't know much about that. I'll try the USB and leave a comment. And no, its not over HDMI its ve DVI.

Comment: Whoever set it up had to access it somehow - so VNC/SSH probably! If plugging in other monitors doesn't work I suspect that it was set to a fixed scanline in xorg.conf, or some other fudge/hack, in order to show properly on a screen that probably wasn't reporting EDID correctly (or similar). An alternate approach is to remove the HDD and attach it to another system - backup the whole of /etc/ (and the rest if you can) and then investigate.

Comment: @Marley, assuming it's running from a desktop session, have you simply tried pressing Alt+F4, Alt+Space, Ctrl+Alt+Down/Right to see if you can close or minimize the application or switch to a different desktop? If it is running in a desktop session, something like Alt+F2 might allow you to open a terminal window. Do you know the name of the digital signage application?

Comment: @pbhj have to try HDD in another pc to see if it will work the same. Didn't think of that option. Thanks for remindin.

Comment: @b_laoshi nothing happens when pressing those buttons man. I'll try the HDD and leave a comment. I don't know what signage  app is that.

Comment: What I mean it's to add it as an additional drive in a second machine, so boot the usual OS and then investigate the hard-drive contents. You might want to read up on `chroot`.

Comment: @Marley, if it were me, I would prefer to know how it is all working, but perhaps there is another course of action. Do you know how the ads were changed in the past? Do they all simply reside in a single folder, and anything in that folder is included in the rotation or is it more complex than that? Is there metadata that specifies where on the screen ads should appear or for how long? You might consider running nmap from another machine to run a port scan and find out what kind of remote management might have been set up.

Answer (score -1):

ALT+F4 combination should close the app and display the XFCE desktop.

Comment: ALT + F4 doesn't do anything man.